# multiple filtering by switch case

Tags: javascript

I need to implement a filter by cards. I have implemented filtering by each color, but how can I filter by multiple parameters? I used switch case to filter the object

Each checkbox item corresponds to a number. The first checkbox shows all cards. Each subsequent one corresponds to the number and color. Help is needed how to filter out several parameters. For example the second (green) and third (orange)

[image]

```js
let checkboxesSelectchecked = document.querySelectorAll(
  "input[type=checkbox][name=one]"
);

checkboxesSelectcheckedZones.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("change", () => {
  

    for (let i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
      let supp = check[i];
      console.log(supp);
      switch (supp) {
        //all
        case "one": {
          colorgreen.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          collororange.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          colorgray.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          colorred.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          break;
        }
        //green
        case "two": {
          collororange.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorgray.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorred.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorgreen.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          break;
        }
        //orange
        case "three": {
          colorgreen.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorgray.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorred.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          collororange.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          break;
        }
        //red
        case "four": {
          colorgreen.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorgray.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          collororange.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorred.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          break;
        }
        //gray
        case "five": {
          colorgray.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          colorgreen.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorred.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          collororange.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          break;
        }
        default:
          console.log("def");
      }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check an object in a `switch case`, then in `switch (true)`. To display one object, use `obj [i] ===`, and to search you can use `includes`

```js
checkboxesSelectcheckedZones.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("change", () => {
  
    let check = Array.from(checkboxesSelectcheckedZones)
      .filter((i) => i.checked)
      .map((i) => i.id);

    for (let i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
      let supp = check.map((i) => i);
      console.log(supp);

      switch (true) {
        //all
        case supp[i] === "one": {
          colorgreen.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          collororange.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          colorgray.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          colorred.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          break;
        }
        //green
        case supp[i] === "two": {
          collororange.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorgray.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorred.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorgreen.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          break;
        }
        case supp.includes("two") && supp.includes("three"): {
          colorgray.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          colorred.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add("collapse");
          });
          collororange.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          colorgreen.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.remove("collapse");
          });
          break;
        }

     
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

ShowAll is selected by default and nothing will get filtered if this option is selected. You can modify it according to your need.

```js
var showAll = true;
document.querySelectorAll(".all")[0].addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  showAll = e.target.checked;
  document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(card => card.classList.remove('collapse'));
  if (showAll) {
    //if showAll is selected then change the checkbox to true for other colors too
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(e => e.checked = true);
  }

});
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".color");
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    var colorType = e.target.name;
    var checked = e.target.checked;
    var cards = document.querySelectorAll(`.${colorType}`);
    if (checked || showAll) {
      cards.forEach(card => card.classList.remove('collapse'));
    } else {
      cards.forEach(card => card.classList.add('collapse'));
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 20%;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.collapse {
  display: none;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' checked="true" class='all' name='all' /> all
<input type='checkbox' checked="true" class='color' name='red' /> red
<input type='checkbox' checked="true" class='color' name='blue' /> blue
<input type='checkbox' checked="true" class='color' name='green' /> green
<input type='checkbox' checked="true" class='color' name='orange' /> orange
<div class='cards'>
  <div class='card red'></div>
  <div class='card red'></div>
  <div class='card green'></div>
  <div class='card green'></div>
  <div class='card blue'></div>
  <div class='card blue'></div>
  <div class='card orange'></div>
  <div class='card orange'></div>
</div>
```